# How to get started on making a dispenser for Indian spices?

Tags: motor, robotic-arm, actuator

I want to make a dispenser system for [Indian spices](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9zdDG.jpg).

- Dispense in multiple of teaspoons (5 ml)
- Handle powdered spices and small seeds like mustard/cumin

I ordered a [spice carousel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00004VWIP) from amazon and was hoping I'll be able to add an actuator to it, but it needs a lot of force to click the dial.

I'm wondering that I would need something similar to sugar dispensers in coffee machines. To start with I want to design individual units, but eventually want to make a solution that can dispense 6 different spices.

I'll appreciate if anyone gives any idea on how to get started on this, thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

You should have a look at small screw conveyors. Either experimentally find out how much you have to turn for your spices or make a feedback loop with a scale.